# Android Studio no longer autocompletes certain imports

Tags: android-studio, dart, import, autocomplete, flutter-packages

After having updated Android Studio to Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1, and migrated some of my projects to null safety and done lots of stuff, I suddenly noticed that when I start typing an import name, Android Studio no longer fills in the full file name, the way it used to! Like if I type:

```dart
import 'mat'
```

it used to suggest to fill in:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

but it no longer does! Instead, it suggests:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
```

so... it finds Dart packages but not Flutter packages? Even if I download a Flutter package by depending on it in the `pubspec.yaml` file and running `flutter pub get`, autocomplete does not seem to find it. I have to write the full file name.

I've also noticed that if I'm in a file in a sub folder of my `lib` folder, say in `lib/screens/screen_a.dart`, and there is also a `screen_b.dart` in that sub folder, I can start typing:

```dart
import 'scr';
```

and AS will suggest:

```dart
import 'screen_b.dart';
```

just as it used to. All very well. But if I want to import a file from a different sub folder, such as `cool_widget.dart` from `lib/widgets/`, I used to type:

```dart
import 'widgets';
```

and it would fill in:

```dart
import 'package:my_project_name/widgets/';
```

from which I could type:

```dart
import 'package:my_project_name/widgets/coo';
```

and get the whole file name:

```dart
import 'package:my_project_name/widgets/cool_widget.dart';
```

That no longer happens! Instead, I now have to type the entire path above before Android Studio seems to recognize it...

I also don't get any autocomplete suggestions for project files within the `lib` folder if I'm in the `lib` folder. It's only if I'm in a sub folder that I get any suggestions for project files, and only from within that same sub folder. This is very difficult, as it slows down the import process considerably.

The problem of not finding other project files is there in several of my projects, including those I haven't yet migrated to null safety, but not in all. The problem of not finding `Flutter` packages but finding `Dart` packages also seems to be there only in some projects, and not necessarily the same as above...

I really can't say what I did that triggered this... Please help?

### Things I've tried

I've done `flutter clean` and `Invalidate caches and restart`. I've also deleted a number of build files and directories, including the entire `.gradle` directory (several GB), and restarted, but nothing helped.

I've also looked through all my settings to see if there's something there, but I didn't find anything obvious...

Comment: Which version of Android Studio you are currently using?

Comment: ...Isn't "Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1" the version of Android Studio? If not, tell me how to find the info you're after, and I'll find it for you.

Comment: Ok,I am also using the same latest version. Have you tried updating you Flutter & Dart Plugin (Android Studio) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by regressions in the new completion protocol introduced in a recent Dart version.

The fix has been implemented in [this commit](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/4b08b7de8bfcb228f01417e501c49f7f63fdf8a3), and will be included in Dart 2.18.

This fix, along with a slew of other autocompletion fixes, are also in the process of being cherry-picked into the stable channel [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49239).

Comment: Ok... so basically, the best I can do is just wait? 

Comment: The latest Flutter betas use Dart 2.18. You could try switching to those if you want.

Comment: Ok, I might try that... Where did you get this information, anyway? Could I read more about it somewhere?

Comment: It works again, now. Dunno how that happened, but when I run `dart --version` in terminal, I get `Dart SDK version: 2.17.6 (stable)`...  Anyway, thanks for answering!